# how can I sort parameters in pyomo?

Tags: sorting, parameters, pyomo

I am working with the Pyomo package(for mathematical modeling in python).I have a parameter defined as: model.D=Param(model.t,model.i) .this is a multi-dimensional parameter. t is for the range of time periods, i is for the range of instances and D is the value of the demand. how can I sort this parameter by its value and get the corresponding t and i ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do all that data cleaning/sorting stuff with basic python *before* you build the model.  Part of this answer depends on the original format of the data and the format you'd like your answer in, but I think the overall gist is clear....

#### Code

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

d = {   0: [1.2, 3.1, 0.5],
        1: [9.5, 2.0, 3.1] }

# a good format to pass in to a parameter, tuple-indexed dictionary
d_data = {(t, i): d[t][i] for t in d for i in range(len(d[t]))}


# now let's sort the values in d for the missing info on order
d_tuples = {t: sorted([(val, idx) for idx, val in enumerate(d[t])]) for t in d}

d_sorted = {t: [temp[1] for temp in d_tuples[t]] for t in d}


print(d_data)
print(d_tuples)
print(d_sorted)

# now set up the model...
m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

m.T = pyo.Set(initialize=d.keys())
m.I = pyo.Set(initialize=list(range(len(d[0]))))  # assumes all d[t] are equal length

m.D = pyo.Param(m.T, m.I, initialize=d_data)

m.pprint()
```

#### Yields:

```
{(0, 0): 1.2, (0, 1): 3.1, (0, 2): 0.5, (1, 0): 9.5, (1, 1): 2.0, (1, 2): 3.1}
{0: [(0.5, 2), (1.2, 0), (3.1, 1)], 1: [(2.0, 1), (3.1, 2), (9.5, 0)]}
{0: [2, 0, 1], 1: [1, 2, 0]}
3 Set Declarations
    D_index : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=True
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     2 :    T*I :    6 : {(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)}
    I : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    3 : {0, 1, 2}
    T : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    2 : {0, 1}

1 Param Declarations
    D : Size=6, Index=D_index, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key    : Value
        (0, 0) :   1.2
        (0, 1) :   3.1
        (0, 2) :   0.5
        (1, 0) :   9.5
        (1, 1) :   2.0
        (1, 2) :   3.1

4 Declarations: T I D_index D
```